# Pre-compile MVC web project with Razor views on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, razor

How to precompile MVC web project (with all Razor views in it) and deploy it using the standard [Visual Studio Azure Publishing tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyhpK.jpg)?

There is no option for me now to use any other Azure deploying tools which could allow to enable this option like it's already exists in local "File System" publishing.

Already read many articles but there doesn't seem an easy way to do it!

Any help?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328439/compile-mvc-and-pre-compile-views-and-deploy-into-azure-webrole

Comment: Otherwise, you can make use of msbuild in PowerShell script to automate everything